# Can't store hashed password retaining format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, hash, cryptography, sha256

Running this query

```
declare @Pass as varchar(32)  = 'Abc123()'
select hashbytes('SHA2_256', @Pass)
```

produces the following output

```
0xA6DAC07A4984EDFF97FCA5D772CE85D6E8752EFBF7287DE525D1EEFFBC09D483
```

but when I store it to the DB, it becomes distorted like this

```
�竀葉￭ﲗ힥칲횅痨אַ⣷턥￮়菔
```

After a while, I realized that the column type is `varchar(max)` and running

```
declare @Pass as varchar(32)  = 'Abc123()'
declare @Hash as varchar(32) = hashbytes('SHA2_256', @Pass)
select @Hash
```

actually reproduces the undesired behavior. I need the "pretty" format to be retained, since I match the hash from the DB with the one I compute based on user's input. I sense that conversion needs to be done in an appropriate way. However, how to find that way is beyond me.

What should I google for?

**edit**

Trying with `nvarchar(32)` produces similar undesirability.

```
declare @Pass as nvarchar(32)  = 'Abc123()'
declare @Hash as nvarchar(32) = convert(nvarchar(32), hashbytes('SHA2_256', @Pass))
select @Hash
```

The schema of the table is here (the culprit column is `PasswordHash`).

[image]

Comment: try nvarchar ..... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @MitchWheat I tried that again, still with the same, sad result. I try to convert now explicitly just as the example suggests. What more can I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into a hex string

```
declare @Pass as varchar(32)  = 'Abc123()'
declare @Hash as varbinary(32) = hashbytes('SHA2_256', @Pass)
select CONVERT([varchar](66), @Hash, 1)
```

You can change the last parameter in the `Convert` from 1 to 2 to avoid the `0x` in the begining of the result string.

Comment: That doesn't produce the same content, though, as the example I'm showing in the question. Also, it seems so excessive with all the conversions for a "simple" hashing using SHA256. (I'm not saying it must be simple but I sense that I'm resolving an issue I don't need to have, if approached correctly.

Comment: Aha, you wanted a hex string. See updated answer. A base64 representation would take less space though.